# SimpleCursorAdapter with ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

can you have a layout with an `imageview` and `textview` for a row in a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a listview?

this would be the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bowler_txt"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bowler"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can it be done in SimpleCursorAdapter with a listview? when I needed images in a listview I always used a custom arrayadapter but never with a cursor.

How would I set the image if it can be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When the view to bind is an `ImageView` and there is no existing `ViewBinder` associated `SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView()` calls `setViewImage(ImageView, String)`. 
By default, the value will be treated as an *image resource*. If the value cannot be used as an image resource, the value is used as an *image Uri*.

If you need to filter in other ways the value retrieved from the database you need a `ViewBinder` to add to the `ListAdapter` as follow:

```
listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
   /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_image_view_id){
           //...
           ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(...);
           return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from @Francesco Vadicamo, this is a fuctions that is part of a larger activity.  I split it off because I needed to call it from multiple areas of the code.  `databaseHandler` and `listView` are defined as a class variables and initialized in `onCreat()`.

```
private void updateListView() {
    // Get a Cursor with the current contents of the database.
    final Cursor cursor = databaseHandler.getCursor();

    // The last argument is 0 because no special behavior is required.
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listview,
            cursor,
            new String[] { databaseHandler.ICON, databaseHandler.BOWLER_TXT },
            new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.bowler_txt },
            0);

    // Override the handling of R.id.icon to load an image instead of a string.
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.imageview) {
                // Get the byte array from the database.
                byte[] iconByteArray = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);

                // Convert the byte array to a Bitmap beginning at the first byte and ending at the last.
                Bitmap iconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iconByteArray, 0, iconByteArray.length);

                // Set the bitmap.
                ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) view;
                iconImageView.setImageBitmap(iconBitmap);
                return true;
            } else {  // Process the rest of the adapter with default settings.
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    // Update the ListView.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```