# android simple cursor adapter imageview and textview

Tags: android, imageview, android-contacts, simplecursoradapter

I have the following code:

```
m_curContacts = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    sortOrder);
String[] fields = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };
m_slvAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list, m_curContacts, fields,
            new int[] { R.id.textview });
```

The layout R.layout.list has 2 elements: a textview and an imageview. I would like to ask how can I add in the m_slvAdapter the imageview?

How to add the following:

```
Uri[] photo = new Uri[] {
     Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentUris.withAppendedId 
         (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,getContentResolver().query
         (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,  
          ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'", null, 
          ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC")
         .getLong(getContentResolver()
         .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, 
          ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'", null, 
          ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC")
         .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))), 
          ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY)
};
```

I want to add near fields and

```
new int[]{R.id.contact}
```

the photo and

```
new Uri[] { 
    contactimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
}
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own ViewBinder. Try to look to this topic where the same issue was answered:
[SimpleCursorAdapter with ImageView and TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510335/simplecursoradapter-with-imageview-and-textview)