# Use SimpleCursorAdapter with Image (path stored in SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have an existing ListView which is filled with some informations from an sqlite database.
The user can create a profile of a dog.
After creating some profiles the list looks like that:

[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aflski1zg8huq2g/Screenshot_2014-03-10-21-13-43.png)
(Sorry for the link but I need 10 Rep for a direct picture)

As you see there is place for a pictures (dog images).

While creating a profile the user can add a picture from his dog which is safed in the internal storage /Android/data/Files/*.jpg (I don't want to add it to the sqlite database).
The name with which it get safed equals the id of the table row in the SQLite database.

Let's say I add a new dog and the id of the row is 134 the the name of the picture is "134.jpg"

Well but atm I have no idea how to add this picture into the ListView.

Any help is welcome!

Last but not least a peace of code how I fetch the data from sqlite:

```
private void fillData() {

    mNotesCursor = helper.fetchAllData();


    String[] from = new String[] { MyDatabaseAdapter.MySQLiteHelper.NAME,
            MyDatabaseAdapter.MySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD,
            MySQLiteHelper.CB_GETREIDE, MySQLiteHelper.CB_FASTENTAG,
            MySQLiteHelper.CB_WOCHENPLAN, MySQLiteHelper.CB_DIET,
            MySQLiteHelper.SP_ART  };


    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label, R.id.gewicht, 
            R.id.getreide,
            R.id.fastentag, 
            R.id.wochenplan, 
            R.id.diet, 
            R.id.spinner
            };

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.hundeliste_item, mNotesCursor, from, to, 0);

    mMyListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

If you need more infos please ask, but I think the important thing I need is more or less the hint/idea how to add the pivture into the listview

**edit:** *(because of the Merlevede's answers)*

Thanks @Merlevede

I tryed the following:

```
//... see post #1 for the upper code part

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.hundeliste_item, mNotesCursor, from, to, 0);



        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
           // Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view 
           public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){

               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hundeliste_item, null);

                   if(view.getId() == R.id.imageView1){

                   File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Android/data/"
                            + getActivity().getPackageName()
                            + "/Files"); 

                   Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + item_id +".jpg");


                   ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(uri.toString()));
return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
                   } 
                   return false; 
             }
            });
    mMyListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it still don't show me the pictures.

Comment: I didn't get it. It is not showing anything? or only the picture?

Comment: The rest is showing as in the first screen.
Just the pictures still don't showing up

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) object to bind an ImageView to a cursor.

Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510335/simplecursoradapter-with-imageview-and-textview) for a good example. I'm copying the example, should the link ever become broken.

```
listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
   /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_image_view_id){
           //...
           ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(...);
           return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. I have still problems. I edited the first post, cause I can't answer my own thread within 8 hours with only 10 Rep :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, though Log() I found the ViewBinder only check item in "to",  R.id.imageView1 do not in "to", the [ if(view.getId() == R.id.imageView1) ] will not go into.
You must add R.id.imageView1 in "to", and also add a string to "from" (even repeated).

```
String[] from = { MyDatabaseAdapter.MySQLiteHelper.NAME,
                  MyDatabaseAdapter.MySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD,
                  MySQLiteHelper.CB_GETREIDE,
                  MySQLiteHelper.CB_FASTENTAG,
                  MySQLiteHelper.CB_WOCHENPLAN,
                  MySQLiteHelper.CB_DIET,
                  MySQLiteHelper.SP_ART,
                  MySQLiteHelper.SP_ART };
int[] to = { R.id.label,
             R.id.gewicht, 
             R.id.getreide,
             R.id.fastentag, 
             R.id.wochenplan, 
             R.id.diet, 
             R.id.spinner,
             R.id.imageView1 };
```